# Append Two DataFrames - Null Error - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to append two DataFrames using Python Pandas, but I am receiving a null error. How can I resolve this?

**Here's the first DataFrame (after I load to Python):**

```
    name    State
0   Tom     NY
1   Lee     CA
```

**Here's the second DataFrame (after I load to Python) with no header:**

```
    0      1
0   Jon    FL
1   Tan    NJ
```

I attempt to append the DataFrames using:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

The result is:

```
    name    State   0    1 
0   Tom     NY     NaN  NaN
1   Lee     CA     NaN  NaN
0   NaN     NaN    Jon   FL
1   NaN     NaN    Tan   NJ
```

I want the result to be:

```
    name    State
0   Tom      NY
1   Lee      CA
2   Jon      FL
3   Tan      NJ
```

I've made the following attempt, but it doesn't work:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
```

Here is my second unsuccessful attempt:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Align your column names and use **`append`**

```
df1.columns = df.columns

df.append(df1).reset_index(drop=True)

# Result

  name State
0  Tom    NY
1  Lee    CA
2  Jon    FL
3  Tan    NJ
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename your column name and then concat them:

```
df2.columns = df1.columns
pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
    name    State
0   Tom      NY
1   Lee      CA
2   Jon      FL
3   Tan      NJ
```